# SPSiteDataQuery for Task List not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, task-list, aggregation

I am creating a visual web part for aggregating all task in all webs of a site collection

I am using `SPSiteDataQuery` to get all tasks but it does not work for Task list

i.e.

> Task List

```
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"107\" />";
```

---

But it work for custom list

> Custom List

```
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"100\" />";
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work for task lists?

Comment: What is the scope of your Query? Please post full code

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Yup issue has been resolved. I am using Task list with Timeline of which serverTemplate is "171". Thanks for Help..!!

Comment: marking my answer as right would be nice

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 List Templates for Tasks:

- Project (Gantt) Tasks (TemplateId: 150)
- Tasks (2010) (TemplateId:107)
- Tasks (TemplateId: 171)

Did you verify that the requested List is using the Template you ask for?